# how to send binary data (del and null characters) through http url

Tags: http

I want to send some binary characters along with HTTP URL, can some one tell me the best way to do it.

Ex: \x7F/a.html (\x7F represents ASCII DEL in binary form)

Sending it with telnet or curl is sending it as a string. Do you think sending on the sockets directly will work

sock.send('GET /test\x7F/a.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 1.1.1.1\r\n') will work??

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTTP spec, the [request-target](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) token can have multiple values "derived" from a URI path. From the URI spec a [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) can only contain printable 7-bit ASCII alphanumeric characters and a few symbols like '-', '.', '%', '~' and others. It does not allow ASCII control characters.

According to the URI spec, path characters outside the printable 7-bit ASCII range should be [percent-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1), so ASCII DEL should be encoded `%7F` and ASCII NULL `%00`.

It's hard to say whether percent-encoding your binary characters “would work” as you do not explain what you expect to get from them. An HTTP request-target is an opaque identifier interpreted by the server, and need not correspond to a file name or actual data. It is perfectly feasible (and common) to refer to binary targets with ASCII alphanumeric request-targets.